# Packet loss sent via ethernet and raw sockets in a producer-consumer

Tags: c++, multithreading, producer-consumer

I am developing a client and a server where the client sends packets and the server receives and treats them through a consumer producer with a circular buffer and then forwards them to the client.

Leaving aside the customer side, the receiver (which would be the producer) looks like this

```
int receiver(int sockfd, shared_ptr<RingBuffer> buffer)
{
    // Set receiving contanitor:
    struct sockaddr_ll saddr; // To store the source address of the packet
    int saddr_len = sizeof(saddr);
    ssize_t rcvDataSize;
    struct ethhdr *eth;
    unsigned char *rcvData = (unsigned char *)malloc(RCV_BUFF_SIZE); // To receive data
    while (1)
    {
        if(!buffer->isFull()){
            do
            {
                rcvDataSize = recvfrom(sockfd, rcvData, RCV_BUFF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, (socklen_t *)&saddr_len);
                if (rcvDataSize <= sizeof(struct ethhdr)) // rcvDataSize <= ethernet
                {
                    std::cerr << "RECEIVER: Error in reading recvfrom() function..." << endl;
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            bufferMutex.lock();
            buffer->push(rcvData);
            // buffer->print();
            bufferMutex.unlock();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The issue is that the receiver doesn't seem to be receiving all the packets and I'm starting to think that as long as the buffer is full and it keeps waiting for the mutex acquisition all the incoming packets are lost. Can anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me. What else would you expect the computer do with the packets?

Comment: I thought that the call to recvfrom would always return the packets in order, and that the operating system's own buffer (or the network card) would handle that. It may also be possible that the buffer fills up during timeout, I have thought about that.

Comment: It appears you are using UDP, or perhaps even raw sockets. UDP packets may arrive out of order, or arrive more than once, or not arrive at all. It's up to the client to deal with that. If you want guaranteed delivery in the correct order, use TCP sockets.

Comment: Yes, I am using raw sockets with a custom protocol.

Comment: @karatefuki And what happens when the buffer is full? The computer cannot tell the other computer to stop sending packets - that is what TCP is for, and you are not using TCP. If all buffers are full, new packets are ignored.